# Chainlink: Data in JSON object not returning

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am using Chainlink to get a value from an API for my smart-contract.

I just want to do a simple Get request as described in Chainlink's documentation. Here is the scripte taken from the documentation:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
  
    uint256 public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e
     * Job ID: 29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() public {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x2f90A6D021db21e1B2A077c5a37B3C7E75D15b7e;
        jobId = "29fa9aa13bf1468788b7cc4a500a45b8";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        request.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.VOLUME24HOUR");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
}
```

The only difference with the example above is that the value ("Myvalue" in this example) I am trying to access is in an array. Here is what the structure of the JSON answer looks like when I call the API using python:

```
{
            "data": [
                {
                    "Myvalue": "0.764",
                    "OtherValue": "4.658"
                    
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "id": "5646843"
            }
}
```

This is my smart-contract code:

```
function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "myURL");
        
        // ----- This is where I suspect the syntax is wrong -----
        request.add("path", "data[0].Myvalue");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        int timesAmount = 10**18;
        request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }

    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
```

When I call requestVolumeData(), the volume value stays at 0. I do not think that the error comes from outside of this function as when I tried to access the "id" in "metadata", it worked.

I suspect the error comes from my JSON spec  `"data[0].Myvalue"`. My question thus is what is the correct syntax to get the value inside an array?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please edit this question so all information can be found on this page? It doesn't help us if we have to flip back and forth between links.

Comment: Could you also include your `fulfill` function? There is a good chance you just have the wrong return type. It looks like the object in your JSON is a string, so you'd have to return a bytes object and convert it to a string.

Comment: I edited my question with the changes you asked for, hope this is easier to read now. About the return type, I would be curious to know why `Myvalue` would be a string but `id` be an integer? Thank you for your help

Comment: “Myvalue” is in quotes in your JSON object, so that gets interpreted as a string

Comment: Found the issue, it was in the JSON path syntax, it should not include "[ ]". Will write a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as suspected, came from the JSON path syntax. It seems that the adapter does not like "[ ]". The correct syntax in this example is:

`request.add("path", "data.0.Myvalue");`